# Como faço para passar essa string em número para calcular em um outro array?

Tags: javascript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

var alunos = new Array();

alunos[0] = new Array();
alunos[0] [0] = "Aline dos Santos";
alunos[0] [1] = "6,5";
alunos[0] [2] = "2,9";

alunos[1] = new Array();
alunos[1] [0] = "Bianca da Silva";
alunos[1] [1] = "7,8";
alunos[1] [2] = "8,6";

var medias = new Array();

medias[0]=((alunos[0][1]+2)*alunos[0][2]/3);

alert(medias[0]);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) do [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) para converte de texto para número, exemplo:

```js
var alunos = new Array();

alunos[0] = new Array();
alunos[0] [0] = "Aline dos Santos";
alunos[0] [1] = "6,5";
alunos[0] [2] = "2,9";

alunos[1] = new Array();
alunos[1] [0] = "Bianca da Silva";
alunos[1] [1] = "7,8";
alunos[1] [2] = "8,6";

var medias = new Array();

medias[0]=((parseFloat(alunos[0][1])+2)*parseFloat(alunos[0][2])/3);

alert(medias[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando você trabalha com operações aritméticas você tem de dar algumas atenções a certos pontos. Veja:

```js
var alunos = new Array();

alunos[0] = new Array();
alunos[0] [0] = "Aline dos Santos";
alunos[0] [1] = "6,5";
alunos[0] [2] = "2,9";

alunos[1] = new Array();
alunos[1] [0] = "Bianca da Silva";
alunos[1] [1] = "7,8";
alunos[1] [2] = "8,6";

var medias = new Array();

medias[0]=((alunos[0][1]+2)*alunos[0][2]/3);

alert(medias[0]);
```

O seu código está lidando com strings e não números. Então peço que pelo seu maior entendimento que procure mais e saber mais e mais. Pequenos erros são para se crescer, ou algo do tipo!

Código funcionando:

```js
var alunos = new Array();

alunos[0] = new Array();
alunos[0] [0] = "Aline dos Santos";
alunos[0] [1] = 6,5; // Retirei aspas
alunos[0] [2] = 2,9; // Retirei aspas

alunos[1] = new Array();
alunos[1] [0] = "Bianca da Silva";
alunos[1] [1] = 7,8; // Retirei aspas
alunos[1] [2] = 8,6; // Retirei aspas

var medias = new Array();

medias[0]=((alunos[0][1]+2)*alunos[0][2]/3);

alert(medias[0]);
```

Não esqueça de deixar o voto (se eu te ajudei)!